# Eigen- Compile errors for Eigen::Map<const Eigen::SparseVector<float>>

Tags: eigen

I'm trying to use Eigen's map feature to map to a sparse vector in memory, but I seem to be unable to compile a declaration to this because 'InnerStrideAtCompileTime' is not a member of 'Eigen::SparseVector<_Scalar, 0, _StorageIndex>'.

Is this unsupported?

Example code:

```
    #include <Eigen/Core>
    #include <Eigen/SparseCore>

    void Foo()
    {
       int innerIndices[10];
       float values[10];
       Eigen::Map<const Eigen::SparseVector<float>> eigenRigOffsets(100, 10, &innerIndices[0], &values[0]);

    }
```

Comment: You need to show a bit more code than that. Can you add an [mcve]?

Comment: Edited above. Just declaring a variable of a map of a sparse vector seems to \fail to compile.

Comment: Does that code actually reproduce your exact error?

Comment: I added the missing bits. That will reproduce the error. I'm using Eigen 3.3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear to not (yet) be supported. There is support for `Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>>` (as shown in the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__SparseQuickRefPage.html)), though that's not what you asked for. Possibly, ggael will have a better answer (or implementation).

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit confusing. For example in SparseMap.h there's a SparseMapBase constructor with the comment "//for vectors", but then no specialization of Map<SparseVector> like there is for SparseMatrix.